# NullPointException when calculating RasterZonalStatistics in geoserver

Tags: geoserver, zonal-statistics, wps

I am trying to generate raster zonal statistics for a raster by providing a custom polygon in geoserver. When I make a ras:RasterZonalStatistics request, I get a `NullPointException error`.

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wcs="http://www.opengis.net/wcs/1.1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0/wpsAll.xsd">
  <ows:Identifier>ras:RasterZonalStatistics</ows:Identifier>
  <wps:DataInputs>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>data</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
        <wps:Body>
          <wcs:GetCoverage service="WCS" version="1.1.1">
            <ows:Identifier>test:tc</ows:Identifier>
            <wcs:DomainSubset>
              <ows:BoundingBox crs="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#32643">
                <ows:LowerCorner>277250.0 2738310.0</ows:LowerCorner>
                <ows:UpperCorner>720100.0 3383110.0</ows:UpperCorner>
              </ows:BoundingBox>
            </wcs:DomainSubset>
            <wcs:Output format="image/tiff"/>
          </wcs:GetCoverage>
        </wps:Body>
      </wps:Reference>
    </wps:Input>
    <wps:Input>
      <ows:Identifier>zones</ows:Identifier>
      <wps:Data>
        <wps:ComplexData mimeType="application/json"><![CDATA[{
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
              [675053.524554,3321241.9569],
[702078.79277,3321703.3667],
[701600.100876,3347772.38452],
[674638.920767,3347308.80149],
[675053.524554,3321241.9569],


    ]
  ]
}]]></wps:ComplexData>
      </wps:Data>
    </wps:Input>
     </wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0">
      <ows:Identifier>statistics</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

Stacktrace:

```
03 Feb 11:05:59 INFO [geoserver.wps] -
Request: getServiceInfo
03 Feb 11:05:59 ERROR [wps.executor] - Process execution failed
org.geotools.process.ProcessException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.execute(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:637)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.ProcessStartupFilter$ProcessStartupWrapper.execute(ProcessStartupFilter.java:50)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.DefaultProcessManager$ProcessCallable.call(DefaultProcessManager.java:224)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.DefaultProcessManager$ProcessCallable.call(DefaultProcessManager.java:192)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.geotools.process.raster.RasterZonalStatistics$RasterZonalStatisticsCollection.<init>(RasterZonalStatistics.java:150)
        at org.geotools.process.raster.RasterZonalStatistics.execute(RasterZonalStatistics.java:122)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.execute(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:621)
        ... 7 more
03 Feb 11:05:59 INFO [geoserver.wps] -
Request: execute
    service = WPS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    identifier:
        value = ras:RasterZonalStatistics
    dataInputs:
        input[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@46d10fe7 (value: data, codeSpace: null)
            reference = net.opengis.wps10.impl.InputReferenceTypeImpl@3183800a (body: net.opengis.wcs11.impl.GetCoverageTypeImpl@26967a60 (service: WCS, version: 1.1.1, baseUrl: null, extendedProperties: {}), encoding: null, href: http://geoserver/wcs, method: POST, mimeType: image/tiff, schema: null)input[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@3774a5b2 (value: zones, codeSpace: null)
            data = net.opengis.wps10.impl.DataTypeImpl@79943a8c
    responseForm:
        rawDataOutput:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@54ba6664 (value: statistics, codeSpace: null)
            mimeType = text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0
```

Further, If I try to change the polygon to CQL,

```
<wps:ComplexData mimeType="text/plain; subtype=cql"><![CDATA[<Intersects>
       <PropertyName>GEOMETRY</PropertyName>
         <gml:Polygon><gml:outerBoundaryIs><gml:LinearRing><gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">76.76559448242188,30.051265218888904 77.05055236816406,30.051265218888904 77.05055236816406,30.268556249047727 76.76559448242188,30.268556249047727 76.76559448242188,30.051265218888904</gml:coordinates></gml:LinearRing></gml:outerBoundaryIs></gml:Polygon>
     </Intersects>]]></wps:ComplexData>
```

I get an error with stacktrace:

```
Request: getServiceInfo 03 Feb 11:09:57 ERROR [wps.executor] - Process execution failed org.geoserver.wps.WPSException: Failed to retrieve value for input zones
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.LazyInputMap.parseInputs(LazyInputMap.java:97)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.LazyInputMap.get(LazyInputMap.java:49)
        at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.buildProcessArguments(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:736)
        at org.geotools.process.factory.AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory$InvokeMethodProcess.execute(AnnotationDrivenProcessFactory.java:616)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.ProcessStartupFilter$ProcessStartupWrapper.execute(ProcessStartupFilter.java:50)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.DefaultProcessManager$ProcessCallable.call(DefaultProcessManager.java:224)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.DefaultProcessManager$ProcessCallable.call(DefaultProcessManager.java:192)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 79; The prefix "gml" for element "gml:Polygon" is not bound.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:284)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
        at org.geotools.xsd.Parser.parse(Parser.java:184)
        at org.geotools.xsd.Parser.parse(Parser.java:139)
        at org.geoserver.wps.ppio.WFSPPIO.decode(WFSPPIO.java:91)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.SimpleInputProvider.getValueInternal(SimpleInputProvider.java:81)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.AbstractInputProvider.getValue(AbstractInputProvider.java:100)
        at org.geoserver.wps.executor.LazyInputMap.parseInputs(LazyInputMap.java:89)
        ... 10 more 03 Feb 11:09:57 INFO [geoserver.wps] - Request: execute
    service = WPS
    version = 1.0.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    identifier:
        value = ras:RasterZonalStatistics
    dataInputs:
        input[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@38edacc (value: data, codeSpace: null)
            reference = net.opengis.wps10.impl.InputReferenceTypeImpl@78f2f6bf (body: net.opengis.wcs11.impl.GetCoverageTypeImpl@c087073 (service: WCS, version: 1.1.1, baseUrl: null, extendedProperties: {}), encoding: null, href: http://geoserver/wcs, method: POST, mimeType: image/tiff, schema: null)input[0]:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@3f33892d (value: zones, codeSpace: null)
            data = net.opengis.wps10.impl.DataTypeImpl@4a1e7cbd
    responseForm:
        rawDataOutput:
            identifier = net.opengis.ows11.impl.CodeTypeImpl@25b62c4f (value: statistics, codeSpace: null)
            mimeType = text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0
```

Comment: I think the clue is in the error message "The prefix "gml" for element "gml:Polygon" is not bound." - your XML is invalid

Comment: @IanTurton if I remove string `gml:` from the complexdata request, making it: `<wps:ComplexData mimeType="text/plain; subtype=cql"><![CDATA[<Intersects>
       <PropertyName>GEOMETRY</PropertyName>
         <Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" "> same as above (character limit)</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
     </Intersects>]]></wps:ComplexData>` I get the `org.geotools.filter.spatial.IntersectsImpl cannot be cast to net.opengis.wfs.FeatureCollectionType`

Comment: You need to add a definition of the gml prefix to the XML not remove the prefix. You also want to use `intersection` not `intersects` as the 2nd one returns true/false not a polygon

Comment: after adding prefix gml and changing it to intersection, I get the error
`The prefix &amp;quot;gml&amp;quot; for element &amp;quot;gml:Polygon&amp;quot; is not bound.`

Comment: You must declare the `gml` namespace - add `xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"` to the polygon element

Comment: I declared `gml` namespace as you suggested, and I get the following error: `Failed to retrieve value for input zones
java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to net.opengis.wfs.FeatureCollectionType`

Comment: Intersects returns a Geometry not a featurecollection

Comment: I am using an intersection: `<wps:ComplexData mimeType="text/plain; subtype=cql"><![CDATA[<intersection>
       <PropertyName>GEOMETRY</PropertyName>
         <gml:Polygon xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><gml:outerBoundaryIs><gml:LinearRing><gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">76.76559448242188,30.051265218888904 77.05055236816406,30.051265218888904 77.05055236816406,30.268556249047727 76.76559448242188,30.268556249047727 76.76559448242188,30.051265218888904</gml:coordinates></gml:LinearRing></gml:outerBoundaryIs></gml:Polygon>
     </intersection>]]></wps:ComplexData>`

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Hi @IanTurton. Apologies for putting a forum question here in SE. I will post it on the mailing list. Thank you again for all your help!